# Alternative to jQuery text() that includes spaces between elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, whitespace

I have some arbitrary body text in a container. I don't control it so I don't know its structure. But something like this:

```
<div id='content-area'>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>A paragraph or two</p>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

That is just a simple example for illustration, in reality it could contain many more items and nested things like tables.

I want to pull out all the text and do some processing on the words used. I'm using the following jQuery to get the text.

```
$('#content-area').text()
// HeadingA paragraph or twoitem 1item 2
```

The problem is that there are no spaces between each tagged item. The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/) says:

> Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.

And all my searches seem to pull up results for removing white space. Is there a way pull out all the text and keep space between elements? Needs to happen in-browser so javascript-ish methods.

Comment: Not a trivial assignment , especially if nesting is deep... what is the use case?

Comment: I was about to post similar question... thanks Rothrock. Here is a fiddler if anyone want to look at it. https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/112/

Comment: @charlietfl, in my project, the use case is, I want to capture duplicate entries from user. (For example: same words with more than one space.) Jquery comparison are not able to catch this difference.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh still not clear what will be compared to what. Any word duplicated anywhere in this text? Or text from another source as comparison? If there is another source issue might be a lot simpler

Comment: @charlietfl, look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/113/. Rothrock, I am sorry if I am diverting your question.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh that trivial example doesn't explain much in context of the question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In case of unknown nested structure you can add blanks to every element

https://jsfiddle.net/3y2yLexv/1/

```
$( "*" ).each(function( index ) {
   $( this ).append(' ');
});

var str = $('#content-area').text();
//Of course you have to trim duplicated blank spaces.
str = str.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
$('#new').text(str);
```

Comment: simple idea...not sure I would have ever thought of this one +1

Comment: Love it. And this has the added benefit of removed double spaces after a period -- yes 2015 and some of the people I work with still do that! Thank you.

Comment: One thing I found is that trying to append space to a table element produces an error. So beware of that.

Comment: I think this changes the html document itself. How can I achieve the same only in JavaScript?

Answer (score 8):

I think jQuery uses the textContent property, which can format your string like that. What you could do instead is traverse the tree looking up for textNodes and append it to a String/Array.

For example:

```js
function getText(domElement) {
  var root = domElement;
  var text = [];

  function traverseTree(root) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(root.childNodes, function(child) {
      if (child.nodeType === 3) {
        var str = child.nodeValue.trim();
        if (str.length > 0) {
          text.push(str);
        }
      } else {
        traverseTree(child);
      }
    });
  }
  traverseTree(root);
  return text.join(' ');
}

var text = getText(document.getElementById('content-area'));
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id='content-area'>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>A paragraph or two</p>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

There's a bunch of text nodes with whitespaces character. What I did to filter them out is to trim the content of the text node and then just check if there's anything beside the whitespace. Might be better to check out which whitespaces character appear and just filter those out.

Comment: You, Sir, are a true hero. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this works for any case. My solution would be a regular expressions that filters tags, whitespaces and new lines from raw html:

`$("#content-area").html().replace(/([\s\n]*<[^>]*>[\s\n]*)+/g," ")`

http://jsfiddle.net/limond/mrnctqcv/1/

EDIT: Of course, this only works if you can avoid any tags that contain html which the user can't see (e.g. `<script>...</script>`)

Answer (score 2):

You could utilize jQuery's `each` method to gather the items and include spacing using string concatenation.

Something along these lines for a crude example:

```
$(function(){
    var output = "";
    $( "li" ).each( function( index, element ){
        output += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $('#output').html(output);
});
```

Feel free to see the output displayed by caching what you want into a variable, which will make it so it is only writing to the DOM once.

http://jsfiddle.net/bq50s8eb/

EDIT:

If you have no idea what the structure is, but you ARE sure that they will all be within a single div, you can use jQuery's universal selector.

```
$(function(){
    var output = "";
    $( "#content-area *" ).each( function( index, element ){
        output += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $('#output').html(output);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bq50s8eb/1/

Comment: OP already stated that structure is unknown and all this does is a very simple list case

Comment: Fair enough. I'll expand.

Comment: as soon as you start nesting this will fail ... parent text will contain child text also

Comment: that doesn't mean it will work in unknown structure...put a `<p>` inside each `<li>` for example...will have duplication of text  http://jsfiddle.net/bq50s8eb/2/

Comment: You've the same problem as I did first time - you have multiply spaces beetween words: Heading_A paragraph or two______item 1_____item_2________item 1_item 2  - it happens because "each" also iterates blank spaces

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me.

```
var textWithSpaces = $('.example span').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get().join(' ');

console.log(textWithSpaces);
// Output: "First Second Third"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding white-space:pre to the css. 
When adding element dynamically using jquery you can do it like:

```
$('<a/>') 
.attr("style", 'white-space:pre;')
.text('    X    ');
```