# Cheerio - Get text with html tags replaced by white spaces

Tags: javascript, cheerio

Today we're using [Cheerio's](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) and notably the method .text() to extract text from a html input.

But when html is

```
<div>
  By<div><h2 class="authorh2">John Smith</h2></div>
</div>
```

Visually on the page, the /div after the word "by" ensures there is a space or a line break.
but when applying cheerio text(), we get as result sth that is wrong:

`ByJohn smith` => which is wrong as we need a white space between By and john.

Generally speaking, is it possible to get the text but in a little special way so that ANY html tag is replaced by a white space. (I'm OK to trim afterwards all multiple whites spaces ...)

We'd like to have as output By John smith

Comment: Perhaps not relevant to the problem but your html example is invalid as the divs enclosing John Smith are both closing tags.

Comment: sure not rleevant to the real issue. thanks, corrected the mistype

Comment: Looks to me you're just not applying the right selector. Take the one you already use and add ` h2` to get the content of the header separately.

Comment: @Mathieu You have to use cheerio?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following regex to replace all HTML tags with a space:

```regex
/<\/?[a-zA-Z0-9=" ]*>/g
```

So when you replace your HTML with this regex, it may produce multiple spaces. In that case you can use `replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')` to replace all spaces with a single space.

**See the result:**

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').innerHTML.replaceAll(/<\/?[a-zA-Z0-9=" ]*>/g, ' ').replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim())
```

```html
<div>
  By<div><h2 class="authorh2">John Smith</h2></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure JavaScript for this task.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(parent.innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " "))
```

```html
<div>
  By<div><h2 class="authorh2">John Smith</h2></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Generally speaking, is it possible to get the text but in a little special way so that ANY html tag is replaced by a white space. (I'm OK to trim afterwards all multiple whites spaces ...)

Just add `' '` before and after all the tags:

```js
$("*").each(function (index) {
    $(this).prepend(' ');
    $(this).append(' ');
});
```

Then deal with multiple spaces:

```js
$.text().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim();
//=> "By John Smith"
```

Since [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) is just a jQuery implementation for NodeJS, you might find [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635444/alternative-to-jquery-text-that-includes-spaces-between-elements) useful as well.

---

Working example:

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(`
    <div>
        By<div><h2 class="authorh2">John Smith</h2></div>
    </div>
`);

$("*").each(function (index) {
    $(this).prepend(' ');
    $(this).append(' ');
});

let raw = $.text();
//=> "        By  John Smith" (duplicate spaces)

let trimmed = raw.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim();
//=> "By John Smith"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cheerio`, you could use `htmlparser2`. It lets you define callback methods for each time it encounters an opening tag, text, or a closing tag while parsing HTML.

This code results in the output string you want:

```
const htmlparser = require('htmlparser2');

let markup = `<div>
By<div><h2 class="authorh2">John Smith</h2></div>
</div>`;

var parts = [];
var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
    onopentag: function(name, attributes){
        parts.push(' ');
    },
    ontext: function(text){
        parts.push(text);
    },
    onclosetag: function(tagName){
    // no-op
    }
}, {decodeEntities: true});

parser.write(markup);
parser.end();

// Join the parts and replace all occurances of 2 or more
// spaces with a single space.
const result = parts.join('').replace(/\ {2,}/g, ' ');

console.log(result); // By John Smith
```

Here's another example on how to use it: https://runkit.com/jfahrenkrug/htmlparser2-demo/1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Cheerio's text() method is mainly to be used to get clean text from scraping. As you have already experienced this is a little different from converting an HTML page to plain text. Using regex replacements to add a space will work, if you only need the text for indexing. For some other scenarios, like converting to audio for example, it won't always work, as you need to differentiate between a space and a new line.

My suggestion would be to use a library for converting HTML to markdown. One option would be [turndown](https://github.com/mixmark-io/turndown).

```
var TurndownService = require('turndown')

var turndownService = new TurndownService()
var markdown = turndownService.turndown('<div>\nBy<div><h2>John Smith</h2></div></div>')
```

This will print out:

```
'By\n\nJohn Smith\n----------'
```

The last line is because of the H2 header. Markdown is far easier to clean, you probably only need to remove URLs and images. Text display is also easier to be read by humans.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a clean text representation of the content, I would recommend using [lynx](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/) (used by Project Gutenberg) or [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/demos.html). Both can be installed and then called from node using `spawn`.  These will provide a cleaner text representation than running puppeteer and using textContent or innerText.

You could also try walking the DOM and adding new lines depending on the node type.

```
import "./styles.css";
import cheerio from "cheerio";

const NODE_TYPES = {
  TEXT: "text",
  ELEMENT: "tag"
};

const INLINE_ELEMENTS = [
  "a",
  "abbr",
  "acronym",
  "audio",
  "b",
  "bdi",
  "bdo",
  "big",
  "br",
  "button",
  "canvas",
  "cite",
  "code",
  "data",
  "datalist",
  "del",
  "dfn",
  "em",
  "embed",
  "i",
  "iframe",
  "img",
  "input",
  "ins",
  "kbd",
  "label",
  "map",
  "mark",
  "meter",
  "noscript",
  "object",
  "output",
  "picture",
  "progress",
  "q",
  "ruby",
  "s",
  "samp",
  "script",
  "select",
  "slot",
  "small",
  "span",
  "strong",
  "sub",
  "sup",
  "svg",
  "template",
  "textarea",
  "time",
  "u",
  "tt",
  "var",
  "video",
  "wbr"
];

const content = `
<div>
  By March
  <div>
    <h2 class="authorh2">John Smith</h2>
    <div>line1</div>line2
         line3
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test2</li>
      <li>test3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
`;

const isInline = (element) => INLINE_ELEMENTS.includes(element.name);
const isBlock = (element) => isInline(element) === false;
const walkTree = (node, callback, index = 0, level = 0) => {
  callback(node, index, level);
  for (let i = 0; i < (node.children || []).length; i++) {
    walkTree(node.children[i], callback, i, ++level);
    level--;
  }
};

const docFragText = [];
const cheerioFn = cheerio.load(content);
const docFrag = cheerioFn("body")[0];

walkTree(docFrag, (element) => {
  if (element.name === "body") {
    return;
  }

  if (element.type === NODE_TYPES.TEXT) {
    const parentElement = element.parent || {};
    const previousElement = element.prev || {};

    let textContent = element.data
      .split("\n")
      .map((nodeText, index) => (/\w/.test(nodeText) ? nodeText + "\n" : ""))
      .join("");

    if (textContent) {
      if (isInline(parentElement) || isBlock(previousElement)) {
        textContent = `${textContent}`;
      } else {
        textContent = `\n${textContent}`;
      }
      docFragText.push(textContent);
    }
  }
});

console.log(docFragText.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers use regex or other libraries, but neither is necessary. The trick to dealing with text nodes in Cheerio is to use `.contents()`:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<div>
  By<div><h2 class="authorh2">John Smith</h2></div>
</div>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($("div").contents().first().text().trim()); // => By
```

If you're not certain the text node will always be the first child, you can grab the first text node among all children as follows:

```js
const text = $(
  [...$("div").contents()].find(e => e.type === "text")
)
  .text()
  .trim();
console.log(text); // => By
```

Hopefully needless to say, but the `"John Smith"` part is standard Cheerio:

```js
const name = $("div").find("h2").text().trim();
console.log(name); // => John Smith
```

See also:

- [How do I get text after single `<br>` tag in Cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74418220/how-do-i-get-text-after-single-br-tag-in-cheerio/74418510#74418510)
- [Get text in parent without children using cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832910/get-text-in-parent-without-children-using-cheerio/74579448#74579448)
- [cheerio: Get normal + text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878673/cheerio-get-normal-text-nodes/73693773#73693773)
- [How to get a text that's separated by different HTML tags in Cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73690939/how-to-get-a-text-thats-separated-by-different-html-tags-in-cheerio/73692854#73692854)
- [Cheerio - How to grab the text following an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76888664/cheerio-how-to-grab-the-text-following-an-element/76889889#76889889)